# Random page comes in between pages

Tags: formatting, landscape

So I have written my report in order. However, some random page that is supposed to be a couple of pages before or after, comes and sits randomly in between other pages that otherwise were perfectly sequenced and flowing. This mostly happens when I switch between landscape and portrait.

I'm not sure if I make sense.

Edit: Here's the preamble if it helps.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[rm,tiny]{titlesec} %added this to change the chapter title's font as default regular text font.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\underline\normalfont\normalsize\centering}

\newlength{\depthofsumsign}
\setlength{\depthofsumsign}{\depthof{$\sum$}}
\newlength{\totalheightofsumsign}
\newlength{\heightanddepthofargument}

\usepackage{pdflscape,booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit} 
\usepackage[font=it,skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption} % italic text for captions

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[3pt]                                               % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                               % numbered entry format
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    }
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}                        % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.99pc]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]                                                  % below code (e.g vertical space)


%to put page numbers as the header
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\centering}{}{0pt}{}
\titlelabel{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-25pt}{4pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\centering}{}{0pt}{}

%koleygr: Redefining chapter to include \thispagestyle{fancy}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\def\chapter{%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter*{#2}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{
\oldchapter*{#1}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter[#1]{#2}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\oldchapter{#1}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
\makeatother

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}




\begin{document}
```

Edit: This is the part of the code I am talking about:

```
%Let's call this picture 1:

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Scree plot for Principal Component Analysis}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{Figure3.png}\
\end{figure}

\clearpage

%Let's call this picture 2:

\begin{figure}
\caption{Loading plot for Principal Component Analysis}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{Figure4.png}\
\end{figure}

\clearpage

%Let's call this picture 3:

\begin{figure}
\caption{Score plot after dimensions reduced through Principal Component Analysis}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{Figure5.png}\
\end{figure}
\end{center}

\clearpage

%Let's all this picture 4.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Modified Mercalli intensity}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.075\columnwidth]{mmi.png}\
\end{figure}

\clearpage

% Let's call this picture 5.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Village-level MMI histogram}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{mmifigure.png}\
\end{figure}

\clearpage

%This is the table.    

\begin{table}
\tiny
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Effect of MMI on probability of occurrence of various earthquake-induced factors}
\begin{tabular} {@{} l *{8}{c} @{}}
\toprule
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) \\
& Temporary & Severely & Low & Water source & Serious & Loss of & Falling\\
& shelter & damaged & yield & damaged & illness & employment & ag prices\\
 \cmidrule(l){2-8}
\emph{Independent variables}\\[1ex]
MMI & 0.298*** & 0.190*** & 0.156*** & 0.187*** & 0.031* & 0.010** & 0.089*** \\
 & (0.025) & (0.035) & (0.006) & (0.029) & (0.003) & (0.004) & (0.020)\\[1ex]

\toprule
N       & 1,652 & 860 & 1,652 & 1,652 & 4,076 & 4,076 & 4,056\\
R\textsuperscript{2} & 0.621 & 0.851 & 0.562 & 0.664 & 0.260 & 0.031 & 0.285\\
\toprule
\end{tabular}
\tiny
\smallskip
\emph{Notes:}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] The regressions use robust standard errors clustered at village level. ***p $<$ 0.01 **p $<$ 0.05 *p $<$ 0.1.
\item[b] No controls were added in the regressions, as the earthquake is totally exegenous to the occurrence of incidents taken as dependent variables.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\pagebreak
```

So, for now, instead of the order I specified above, the order is:

Picture 1
Table
Picture 2
Picture 3
Picture 4
Picture 5

I used `\clearpage` instead of `\pagebreak` because some of these pictures were coming on the same page (like, Picture 2 and Picture 3), and the latter command was not working.

Does it make it clearer?

Comment: latex doesn't do anything randomly, it follows the instructions that you put in the document so if you do not show any code it is impossible to help. Is the text that has moved in a `figure` or `table` environment ?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your comment. I have added the preamble in my main question. Yes, mostly table, because adding a wide table is the reason I did landscape for.

Comment: Also, for command, I used \begin{landscape}....\end{landscape} code. Is that ok?

Comment: you have shown no code that would cause any text to come out of order, so the problem is in code you have not shown. note that the _only_ reason to use `\begin{table}` or `\begin{figure}` is to allow the content to be moved to help with page breaking, so if that is the issue then it is by design. Otherwise impossible to guess unless you show an example.

Comment: `\sectionfont{\underline\normalfont\normalsize\centering}`  can that really work? you are applying  `\underline` just to `\normalfont`

Comment: David, yes, it is working. It is to follow a certain thesis formatting requirement for the section.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, I have added more details in my question. May be that helps?